# What does the colon mean here?

Tags: javascript, typescript, reactjs

Looking at sample SearchKit code (written with react/jsx and es2015), I see the following line in jsx file:

```
const source:any = _.extend({}, result._source, result.highlight)
```

What does the colon between `source` and `any` do/mean?

Comment: Looks like TypeScript.

Comment: But does that colon do?

Comment: It's a type annotation. TypeScript is compiled to JavaScript; it's *not* JavaScript however.

Comment: OP is probably talking about https://github.com/searchkit/searchkit-demo/blob/master/src/app/src/App.tsx (which is indeed a TypeScript file)

Comment: Could be Flow as well, couldn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a TypeScript [typehint](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html). This indicates that the variable `source` can be of `any` type.

Comment: I only have Babel presets for es2015 and jsx - how does it compile TypeScript?

Comment: I personally never used es6/jsx along with typescript. I'm not sure it's possible but you could experiment with your own pipeline